# server request security with tokens

Tags: javascript, php, session, xmlhttprequest, csrf

I have built a browser game and now I'm working on making it a bit more secure. Since all server requests are initiated from javascript even kids could tamper data on the server. I've been reading through questions on stackoverflow and implemented sending/receiving a token in my requests however I am regenerating this token on every request to the server and send the new one back to the client for the next call. Requests are made through https and are of type POST.

Here's the token flow on client side:

```
var token = 'abcd1234';

$.ajax({
   url: "index.php",
   type: "post",
   data: {
      method: "score",
      value: 50
   }
});

$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, o){
    o.data += '&token=' + token;
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, o){
    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    token = data.token;
});
```

And on server side:

```
if (!isset($_POST['token']) || ($_POST['token'] != $_SESSION['token']))
{
    die();
}
else
{
    // generate new token and send it back along with the response
}
```

So my question would be if this token increases the security of my server requests or not and what can be done to further increase the security?

**EDIT** This is a facebook game, all code is javascript and the server side simply handles updating the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont really think tokens do alot when using Ajax.

You should just validate all your forms and data server sided with the users session because the login itself is the most realiable way to identify a user.

A token an merely help to make session stealing/riding harder but if you code your session handle to logout the user on changed IP adress this should be fair secure enough.

I have an online game aswell and I dont do more but validate all forms and values against injection, valid data and check the login/session every time correctly and never had any bad experience with that.

One more thing I do is security issue is that you should flag your admin accounts with a special attribute that it requires a special IP range to login, then I fetch the ip range with a whois lookup on ripe.net and enter it into the database and look if the users actual IP is inside the min and max ip, this way maybe 1 of 1000 attackers would have the correct IP adress to login with the admin account even if they achive the login data.

Remember that the generated token will be received and send with every normal ajax request and someone who want to harm you and your page will analyse your form and request data and then simply copy that process.

It will make it harder for script kiddies, but not for professional intruders.
Its all just a matter about how paranoid you are about security issues and how skilled your possible attackers are.

Comment: Thanks for you input but the whole process happens on client side, user accounts, etc are there. The server side just updates the database, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

As Steini already stated the ONLY reliable login system is done with session. The client side solution has got infinity security issues.

You can for example make the system using session and than use Javascript to ask php if the user is logged, and which privilege it has.

This said you can use PDO to increment the security, you can also fetch all the data from all the form and all variables that are passed through browser alone to exclude some issues.

Without a secure login system your game will be a security bomb and will create you trouble soon or later.